# Python script hangs

Tags: python

I know very little about Python so I hope this question isn't too vague.

I'm trying to run the python script quarqd_messages.py located here:

https://github.com/markrages/antsrm/tree/master/firmware/qapy

The command line I'm using is:
**"quarqd_messages.py --header > message-headers.h"**

However, it hangs and the output file is 0kb.

I tried debugging with pdb and when I do so, it steps through to this line:

```
       for line in fd.readlines():
```

and then it hangs.  I did read in another answer that .readlines() should be avoided for memory reasons, but removing it had no effect.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: In general if readlines() hangs it's waiting on input from *somewhere*.

Answer (score 1):

In this case, `fd` is `sys.stdin`; the script is trying to read data from the stdin pipe of the script.

You need to pipe data into this script; perhaps something like `quarqd_messages.py --header < somedatafile`?

Answer (score 0):

I think the way the program is written, it's expecting data to be passed in from stdin:

```
ms.load(sys.stdin)
```

so you need:

```
something | quarqd_messages.py --header > message-headers.h
```

Comment: Ahh.. this makes a lot of sense as the command line I was using was how I was interpreting the makefile calling it.. Apparently I need to learn more about Makefile scripting as well.  Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

This is another way of doing it, in a single line

```
quarqd_messages.py --header < MessageSet.txt > message-headers.h
```

it uses both the input and output redirections. `MessageSet.txt` is being redirected into the `quarqd_messages.py` (input redirection) and the output of the program is being redirected to `message-headers.h` (output redirection). To make this clear, you can write the same command with brackets.

```
(quarqd_messages.py --header < MessageSet.txt) > message-headers.h
```